# Ошибка внедрения зависимости в Swagger для аттрибута [FromService] метода контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dependency-injection, swagger

уважаемые разработчики. Мне нужно помочь научить Swagger работать с зависимостями для параметров методов контроллера, гугление не помогло.

Проект на ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1
Есть метод контроллера, который берется из строки запроса вместе с параметрами фильтрации. Мне нужно внедрить зависимость на параметр интерфейса IRequestParam в тип RequestParam:

```
    public class RequestParam : IRequestParam
    {
        public RequestParam();

        public int? Skip { get; set; }
        public int? Take { get; set; }
        public List<string> FilterFieldList { get; set; }
        public List<string> FilterValueList { get; set; }
        public List<FilterType> FilterTypeList { get; set; }
        public SortItem SortItem { get; set; }
        public bool? RemoveInnerFilter { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRequestParam
    {
        int? Skip { get; set; }
        int? Take { get; set; }
        List<string> FilterFieldList { get; set; }
        List<string> FilterValueList { get; set; }
        List<FilterType> FilterTypeList { get; set; }
        ISortItem SortItem { get; }
        bool? RemoveInnerFilter { get; set; }
    }

    public class SortItem : ISortItem
    {
        public SortItem();

        public string SortField { get; set; }
        public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISortItem
    {
        string SortField { get; set; }
        SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

Зависимости определены в Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
    services.AddTransient<ISortItem, SortItem>();
    services.AddTransient<IRequestParam, RequestParam>();
```

Метод контроллера выглядит так:

```
[HttpGet("total")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTotalAsync([FromQuery][FromServices] IRequestParam filter)
{
   var result = await service.GetTotalAsync(_modelName, filter);
   return Ok(result);
}
```

Однако сваггер не может разрешить зависимость при выполнении запроса
https://localhost:5001/MyController/list?SortItem.SortField=Name
и возвращает ошибку

> Could not create an instance of type 'DataCore.Interface.Filter.IRequestParam'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'filter' parameter a non-null default value

Comment: `services.AddScoped()` пробовали?

Comment: пробовал 

`services.AddScoped<ISortItem, SortItem>();
services.AddScoped<IRequestParam, RequestParam>();`
не помогло

Comment: Он логично говорит что не может создать инстанс, т.к. это интерфейс. [FromServices] и [FromQuery] перемешивать как то странно.